# Firebase function featuring val undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a push notification function whenever the database update sends a notification but the function gets an error at first

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
>       at exports.fcmSend.functions.database.ref.onCreate.event (/srv/index.js:9:31)
>       at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
>       at /worker/worker.js:825:24
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

my function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.fcmSend = functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onCreate(event => {

  console.log('event', event)

  const message = event.after.val()
  const userId  = event.params.userId
  const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: message.title,
          body: message.body,
          icon: "https://placeimg.com/250/250/people"
        }
      };


   admin.database()
        .ref(`/fcmTokens/${userId}`)
        .once('value')
        .then(token => token.val() )
        .then(userFcmToken => {
          return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFcmToken, payload)
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log("Sent Successfully", res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('err', err);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [onCreate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onCreate) listener doesn't have an "after". Only `onUpdate()` and `onWrite()` have before and after. It should work just to do:

```
event.val();
```

Comment: it worked thanks but I think there are more things wrong have any documentation to indicate me?

Comment: You also need to `return` your whole promise chain starting with `admin.dateabase().ref(...)`

Comment: It returns undefined userId now wanted a documentation / tutorial to understand the part of when to change the database to give a notification to a fcmToken in db.

Comment: At this point you're asking for more general guidance than usually works well on Stack Overflow. If you feel like my original answer solved the problem described in the text above, I'd appreciate if you marked it as correct. As to where to go next, https://firebase.google.com/docs has lots of content but I'm not sure where exactly to point you.